# Proof using induction: $r!$ divides the product of $r$ consecutive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

> Prove by induction that the product $$n(n+1)...(n+r-1)$$ of any $r$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $r!$.

In the inductive case i've$$n(n+1)...(n+k-1)(n+k)$$
I was not able to find a way to prove this is divisible by (k+1)!.
I try to use distributive property in (n+k).

Comment: Isn't it easier to avoid induction and just notice that $\binom{n+r-1}{r}=\frac{n(n+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+r-1)}{r!}$ is obviously an integer number?

Comment: @Jack D' Aurizio ,since it is integer we won't need induction am I right?

Answer (score 1):

> The product of $r$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $r$.

Proof: Okay, I've just remodeled my answer. For $r=1$ it is obvious.

Let it be true for $r=k$. For $r=k+1$, we will induct by the integer $m$, while showing that $(k+1)! | m(m+1)...(m+k)$. So suppose that $(k+1)! | m(m+1)...(m+k)$.We want to show that $(k+1)! | (m+1)(m+2)...(m+k+1)$.

How we do this is as follows: define $m_k = (m)(m+1)...(m+k)$. Then,
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& (m+1)_k =  (m+1)_k -m_k + m_k\\
& =(m+1)...(m+k)(m+k+1-m) + m_k\\
& =(k+1)(m+1)_{k-1} + m_{k}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Now, note that $k! | (m+1)_{k-1}$ by induction on $k$, hence $(k+1)! |(k+1)(m+1)_{k-1}$. On the other hand, by induction on $m$, $(k+1)! | m_{k}$. Hence, $(k+1)!$ divides their sum, which is $(m+1)_k$. Now, we are done by induction on $m$, and then by induction on $k$.

Comment: OP wants it divisible by $r$-factorial, not just by $r$.

Comment: To show that $(k+1)!$ divides $A$, it does not suffice to show that both $k+1$ and $k!$ divide $A$. E.g. if $k=3$, $6 \mid A$ and $4 \mid A$ together do not imply that $24 \mid A$.

Comment: @user133281 I understand. I wrote this much of the answer, I''m still editing it.

Comment: You prove that $k!  | n(n+1)\ldots(n+k)$ and then that $k+1 | n(n+1)\ldots(n+k)$, but how do you conclude $k!(k+1)  | n(n+1)\ldots(n+k)$? It seems you can only conclude $\operatorname{lcm} (k!, k+1) | n(n+1)\ldots(n+k)$ from that.

Comment: @JoelCohen Corrected. I reformed my entire answer using a double induction argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Without induction:** The expression
$$
n(n+1)\cdots(n+r-1)
$$
counts the number of words of length $r$ with all distinct letters, from an alphabet of $n+r-1$ letters.
But this is also equal to the number of *sets* of $r$ letters, times $r!$ since there are $r!$ ways of arranging the set into a word. Thus, the above expression is divisible by $r!$.

Answer (score 1):

If $r=1$ the theorem obviously holds true.
Let $r$ be the least natural number for which the theorem does not hold true and $a$ the least natural such that $R_a=(a+2)(a+3)\cdots (a+r+1)$ is not divisble by $r!$.
Obviously, $R_a>r!$ and from now we suppose that any product of $r-1$ numbers is a multiple of $(r-1)!$

We can see that  $R_a-R_{a-1}=$
$(a+2)(a+3)\cdots (a+r)[a+r+1-(a+1)]=(a+2)(a+3)\cdots (a+r)\cdot r$.

It is obvious that $(a+2)(a+3)\cdots (a+r)$ is a product of $r-1$ numbers which means it is divisible by $(r-1)!$ (from induction hypothesis)so, multiplying by $r$ , it becomes a multiple of $r!$.
Hence $r!\mid R_a-R_{a-1}$ and $r!\mid R_{a-1}$ so, $r!\mid R_a$ which contradicts the definition of $a$.